# How to Stop Services from activity

Tags: android, android-service, alarmmanager

I am new for services and I can't find a way to stop services which is started by alarm manager.

This is the code to stop service:

```
    stopservices()
    {
    CancelAlarm(getApplicationContext());
    Intent intent1 = new Intent(this, CrService.class);        
    stopService(intent1);
     }

 // method Cancel alarm
 public void CancelAlarm(Context context)
    {
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, ReceiverPositioningAlarm.class);
        PendingIntent sender = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, 0);
        AlarmManager AvdhiCralarm = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        AvdhiCralarm.cancel(sender);
        sender.cancel();
       // stopService(new Intent(this, CrService.class));
    }
```

Comment: try change this to yourclassname.this , yourclass name the name of class where you call your service

Comment: let me know if this work with you , or support more code and your error stack if you got one

Answer (score 0):

```
stopservices()
    {
    CancelAlarm(getApplicationContext());

     }

 // method Cancel alarm
 public void CancelAlarm(Context context)
    {
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, ReceiverPositioningAlarm.class);
        PendingIntent sender = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, 0);
        AlarmManager AvdhiCralarm = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        AvdhiCralarm.cancel(sender);
        sender.cancel();
     // just write your context before call stop service & your name class before this
       context.stopService(new Intent(Yourcalss.this, CrService.class));
        ^                                ^
        |--------------------------------|
    }
```